# Intellij, what are web faces really do, and why does it keep insisting on /web directory

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, war

Having issues with web.xml updates not being reloaded even on a tomcat restart

Spent the entire day on this to fix it so that can work as should.

I usually have web faces auto configure, wether I want them or not, but Intellij insist on the directory /web , despite me not using that at all, and at times even creates it for me.

What are web faces for? Maybe that will resolve my issue? But how can intellij stop insisting on the **web** directory?

I've even configured:

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>assets</directory>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

but it still insisting on web directory. Problem is that I have several modules, and I find that reconfiguring the project in the future makes the manual labor unsustainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE follows Maven rules. If you try to executing Maven's war:war goal you should get the same result. With the configuration like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                <directory>assets/</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maven adds `assets` (relative to pom.xml file) as a web resource directory and IDE adds it in Web facet settings.
If you want to exclude default `webapp` directory, check [this thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/war-war-overrides-webapp-content-from-webapp-resources-td5160326.html)

For instance:

```
<warSourceDirectory>resources</warSourceDirectory>
```

Comment: thanks, i've mentioned that too. The link you provided shows how to exclude files and folders under webapp directory. Do you have an example to exclude entire webapp ?

Comment: What do I change <warSourceDirectory></warSourceDirectory> to ?

Comment: I just added it as resources. I guess that works fine.